# Magento2 : How to install patch CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch

Tags: patches, magento2.1.6

Today **CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch** patch has released by Magento for resolve Image Resize Issue with Magento version 2.1.6

[Image Resize Issue with Magento version 2.1.6](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_216-imageresize.html)

How can I install the patch? I can't find out any instruction for how to install patch. If any one have solution, please suggest to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just applied the patch file.

If you have git installed on your environment just use the following copy the patch on you magento root folder.

Then use:

```
$ git apply MAGETWO-67805-2017-05-17-03-04-03.patch
```

There is no verbose first time but if you try second time you will see

```
error: patch failed: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageBlockBuilder.php:120
error: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ImageBlockBuilder.php: patch does not apply
```

Checked the mentioned files and they are up to date

Comment: I applied and got same error.

Comment: Check one of the files to make sure changes were applied. The error means that the files were identical in content which means patch was applied

Comment: Let me check it from my side.

Comment: Changes applied.

Comment: i got error not apply

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/patch-command-examples to follow steps to apply the patch using patch file.

Thank you

Comment: I have tried but not success, can you please give command which you have used.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

> 1. Download the patch file from magento official website.
> 2. Upload it into the root folder of your magento store.
> 3. Make one file with the name of `patch.php` in root directory, write following code in it.

```
<?php
    print("<PRE>");
    passthru("/bin/bash CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch");
    print("</PRE>");
    echo "Done";
?>
```

> 4. The patch file name should be CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch.
> 5. Run the file from the browser. You should receive success message screen once you run patch.php from the browser.
> 6. Clear and flush the magento cache.

In this way you can install any magento patches easily.
Hope it helps you !!

Comment: I already tried. I guess issue with .patch file.

Comment: its work on magento 2